# UICollectionViewCells with dynamic heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

What would the pattern be for sizing a `UICollectionViewCell` based on some content I've downloaded? I wouldnt know the size when the cell gets created - it would be sometime after my content has downloaded that the cell would callback with its height. What would I call on the collectionview to have it re layout its cells?

I've faced this with tableviews and ended up calculating the height based on the strings and controls in the cell. But in that case essentially everything was a function of data already in my model. Thats not the case here.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of cells you will displaying (e.g. a small # of cells), simply calling `[UICollectionView reloadData]` will do the trick once you know the different heights from that network callback.

Comment: But don't I need to let the collection view know what the sizes at index paths are?

Comment: Yes, in the delegate method `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` you could check if the network request is complete and give it the static values if it hasn't come back. Then, you would provide the dynamic values if that request has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the the RFQuiltLayout can solve your problem.

Use the function

- (CGSize) blockSizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Here is the link https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout